# It is currently in use by another Gradle instance. , it`s an android studio problem or mac Mojave permission

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.

i have traied android studio 2.3 and 3.2 the same problem ?

Timeout waiting to lock Build Output Cleanup Cache (/Volumes/data/Teachinnovety/Projects/teamy/Kartero mobile app/platforms/android/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.

Answer (score 3):

Remove  lock files in the gradle cache by  this command:

```
find ~/.gradle -type f -name "*.lock" | while read f; do rm $f; done
```

Comment: try this once, 1. Start task manager find/ verify that there are NOT TWO instances of java.exe running. Step 2. Just kill any one java.exe or both and start Android Studio again

Comment: sometime this reason would be case to this problem,Your build.gradle file likely contains multiple statements of minSdkVersion. Possibly in defaultConfig{} block and productFlavors{} block. Make sure you are only declaring minSdkVersion once in the build file.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a known problem when using Gradle on a project located on an exFat formatted external drive, according to this issue about not being able to lock file on exFAT drive: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4329

Comment: Using Android Studio gradle plugin version 7.0.0 fixed my issue on an exFat formatted drive for some reason.